# Is it possible to import a SharePoint Online list template (STP) to SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I have a special situation here where I need to get a few SharePoint Online lists into an older SharePoint 2010 instance.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need the content or just the list structure?

Comment: I need the list and content for sure.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can do this using Sharegate.

Comment: ShareGate says it supported, but I was wondering if there is a way to do it without any third-party utilities.